# Project download from QFieldCloud failed "project does not contain a valid QGIS project file"

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

On my mobile device when using QField I can't download the project from the QFieldCloud, it says "the project does not contain a valid QGIS project file".
Before I've set up a project for QFieldCloud, packaged it in QGIS with the addon QFieldSync, uploaded it to QFieldCloud and it definitely contains a QGIS project file. What may cause an invalid QGIS project file?

My project contains both feature layers for offline use and WMS layers. I'm using QGIS 3.16 and the latest QField.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I browsed the Internal Storage I could not even find the QField folder. According to this source (https://www.opengis.ch/de/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%ef%bf%bc/), it should be named ch.opengis.qfield and should be located in "Internal storage" -> "Android" -> "Data".

I didn't solve the cloud problem, but the workaround described here (https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/tutorials/get-started-qfs/) worked for me:

1. Create a QField package [on your PC]. This is a working copy in a separate folder.
2. Copy the QField package to the target device.
3. Go out and collect data.
4. Copy the modified data back to your desktop computer.
5. Synchronize the modified data with your database or files.

To open the package on your device open the app, select "Open local file" -> "Internal Storage" -> (your specified folder, navigate to the project).
You can access the modified project in the internal storage on your phone via your PC after editing. Not the most elegant way, but at least it's possible to work on your data in the field.

BTW: I named the folder on my device "ch.opengis.qfield", as specified here (https://www.opengis.ch/de/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%ef%bf%bc/). Interestingly, after creating and using the folder a new folder also named ch.opengis.qfield turned up on my device in "Android" -> "Data", where a folder like this should have been from the start. Not quite sure what it means, but maybe it does help someone with more Android related experience...

Answer (score 0):

After several tries setting up my qfield cloud project adding one layer after the other I figured out some points that may have caused the problem of an invalid qgs file in qfield cloud:

- the WMS layer needs a password (licensed) and the pw is not stored within the project file - solution: authentification needs to be set to "basic" in the WMS layer properties
- one layer (in my case a polygon vector layer) has geometry problems - solution: run "repair geometry"